# stylesheet_link_tag が precompile された assets を参照してくれない時の対処法

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Railsで使用してるRubyのバージョンを`2.0.0`から`2.1.5`にアップデートした時からdeploy時に`assets`が読み込まれないエラーが起きるようになってしまいました。

アセットのプリコンパイルが正常に動かいて無いかと疑い
サーバーにログインし一度 `${APP_DIR}/public/assets/assets-*`を削除し、

`RAILS_ENV=production ./bin/rake assets:precompile`で`application-80d9a9c586007ba0c9f85e11beee1b41.css`のようにコンパイルされたアセットが生成されるのは確認したのですが、`stylesheet_link_tag`で正常に参照されないらしくサイトのソースにて確認すると

```
<link href="/assets/application-d220bb0a13b51cdccc9467ae62215336.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

と、別の存在しないリンク先をさしてしまっています。

`javascript_include_tag`も同様に正常に参照できていません。

上記のように `stylesheet_link_tag` が生成されたファイルへのリンクを正常に生成できない時の原因としてはどのようなものが考えられるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CapistranoからUnicornを制御するタスクとして[ここのコード](http://qiita.com/satococoa/items/9b0cc416ffc042680b9b)を流用して使っているのですが、
`unicorn:restart`だと unicornが再起動せず `unicorn:stop` `unicorn:start`すると正常にリンクが参照させるようになりました。

以下に該当部分のコードを転載しておきます。

```
namespace :unicorn do
  task :environment do
    set :unicorn_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
    set :unicorn_config, "#{current_path}/config/unicorn/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.rb"
  end

  def start_unicorn
    within current_path do
      execute :bundle, :exec, :unicorn, "-c #{fetch(:unicorn_config)} -E #{fetch(:rails_env)} -D"
    end
  end

  def stop_unicorn
    execute :kill, "-s QUIT $(< #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)})"
  end

  def reload_unicorn
    execute :kill, "-s USR2 $(< #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)})"
  end

  #...

  desc "Start unicorn server"
  task :start => :environment do
    on roles(:app) do
      start_unicorn
    end
  end

  desc "Stop unicorn server gracefully"
  task :stop => :environment do
    on roles(:app) do
      stop_unicorn
    end
  end

  desc "Restart unicorn server gracefully"
  task :restart => :environment do
    on roles(:app) do
      if test("[ -f #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)} ]")
        reload_unicorn
      else
        start_unicorn
      end
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```